# Does a column of only zeros provide any information in a data analysis?. What if it has missing values?

Tags: data-science

I have a tricky question someone asked me:

I got a bunch of columns with data to predict some future sales.
There are a bunch of these columns that use a lot of memory and only got zeros. The question is: Can I just remove these columns from my analysis?

Second part. What if the columns that only have zeros also have missing values. What do you do?

Comment: Just to be clear. The study is done, so you should not expect to see any data in the future appearing as non-zero at this point.

My answer was that you can drop the columns, except the ones that have missing values. You can replace the missing values with ones because that is some information right there.

Answer (score 0):

Analyzing datasets with large numbers of zeros can indeed be a waste of computational resources (see sparse matrices computation), especially since they may not be contributing any meaningful information. In fact, they might even add noise to your dataset, obscuring any relationships you might find otherwise.

But there are cases were zeros can be incredibly meaningful. For example, if you were trying to predict future sales of products based on units sold (count data), with each column representing a month of sales, you might want to keep the zeros as they provide insight into sales of your product during those specific months.

Removing missing values is definitely tricky, and they can often be a sign that you might need to re-examine the data collection process for explanation; is there a reason why the data is missing, or does the missing value mean something (e.g. sometimes zeros can be coded as NAs)?

How you deal with zeros/missing values varies greatly based on the domain you're in, the specific question you're trying to answer, and what exactly the meaning of your data/columns are. So it's kind of hard to answer without knowing much about the data itself.